# Track what set zsh option

Tags: zsh

Currently I have `noautomenu` `on` but search through entire `homeuser` I seem can't find any line that set this option, `rg --hidden noautomenu .` that make me believe some plugin or scripts set it automatically without my notice.

So can we track down what script/plugin set zsh option?

Comment: Again, run `zsh` with `zsh -x` to see what turns it on.

Comment: See also [Which startup file is being used by my shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/367322)

Comment: Guess someone's trying to do some magic there: `+/home/user/.zsh/SCRIPT.zsh:21> unsetopt automenu`